# Why output value of Uniswap-2 SDK for token prices is different than those on its site?

Tags: uniswap, ethers.js, price

I use `fetchPairData` method from uniswap-v2 SDK to quote two tokens conversion rates:

```
const uniswapPair: Pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(
    new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, baseToken.address, 18),
    new Token(ChainId.MAINNET, quoteToken.address, 18),
    provider
);
console.log(  Number(uniswapPair.token0Price.toFixed(pair.baseToken.decimals)) );
```

The return value for the token price is slightly different from the quoted value on uniswap website (This is the case for any tested pairs such as AAVE/DAI or LINK/DAI).
What is going on wrong with this method of price inquiry?

Comment: Are you looking for the MidPrice or ExecutionPrice? See https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/pricing/